# How to avoid arrow heads reaching into boxes?

Tags: svg, graphviz, dot

I create SVG output with dot. When I set `penwidth = 2` for nodes and edges, the arrowheads point slightly inside the boxes. Is there a way to avoid this? Maybe by drawing the nodes *after* the edges? Or by reducing the length of the edges/arrows to 95%? I've tried to find an attribute that would allow this, but could not find something that worked.

**NOTE:** Effect can't be seen when converting to png or jpg. Create SVG with `dot -Tsvg file.dot > file.svg` and view in browser.

This is my dot file:

```
digraph configure {

  node [
    shape     = box,
    fontname  = "Courier",
    style     = "filled",
    fillcolor = "#cccccc",
    penwidth  = 2
  ];

  A [label = "configure.in"];
  B [label = "autoconf\nGNU m4", fillcolor = ".7 .3 1.0"];
  C [label = "configure"];
  X [label = "cfg.hin", fillcolor = "#eeeeee"];
  Y [label = "cfg.h", fillcolor = "#eeeeee"];

  edge [
    fontname  = "Palatino-Italic",
    fontsize  = 9,
    penwidth  = 2,
    arrowsize = 1
  ];

  A -> B [label = "  is input to"];
  B -> C [label = "  creates"];

  subgraph cfg {
    rank = same;
    rankdir = LR;
    X -> C [label = "is input to  "];
    C -> Y [label = "creates  "];
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have this issue - on graphviz version 2.26.3 here

Comment: As long as penwidth for nodes is >= penwidth for edges you should be safe.